# Change display resolution on remote execution

Tags: windows, powershell, selenium-webdriver, administration, windows-server

I'm executing Selenium webdriver tests on remote test server using powershell script (from Jenkins CI server hosted on Windows server 2008r2, on Windows server 2012 target machine, if it is important). I want to change the default display resolution.

[QRes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qres/) console utility tells me that only 1024x768 resolution is available (qres /s command).

Is there ideas to increase the display resolution, let us say, to 1920x1080? May be the resolution is stored somewhere in registry? May be there is a way to emulate the video card?

P.S. It is enough to change the resolution for one time, no dynamic change of resolution required.

**UPD**:
I'm using powershell remoting session. No, it is not looks like RDP session.

Example:
powershell .\run.ps1

where run.ps1 looks like:

```
$sc = {
    #this code section is executed on remote computer.
    #it runs firefox.exe, chrome.exe, making snapshots, etc.
    powershell C:\path\on\remote\server\run-tests.ps1
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SEPER-TEST-SERVER" -ScriptBlock $sc
```

One of the troubles I don't event understand what the video device it actually using, but I can create snapshots, etc. May be, there is a man who can explain me how it is actually  working:)).

I want to find the how to change the display (virtual display?) resolution once. It can be script, registry change, etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Change the display resolution for what? Are you using an RDP session and want to change the resolution of the window, or do you mean change the size of the PowerShell window, or do you mean you want the PowerShell script to change the display resolution at the console for that server? Or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround using [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) , instead of running the browser on local machine.

Answer (score -1):

@2xmax: If I read your original question correctly, I believe that you wanted to set the screen resolution to a larger size to eliminate the following errors from your end 2 end tests.

```
"Element is not clickable at point (996, 92)"
```

or other such error that occurs because the element that you want is off screen.  I am having the same problems with my end 2 end tests.

I am unclear on how using "Selenium Grid" solved your problem.  Can you please elaborate so that I can follow your example?  Thanks.